# Ignore Case of indexOf() with ArrayLists

Tags: java, arraylist

```
static void seaArray()
    {
        String searchTerm = key.nextLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < name.size(); i++)
        {
            if (name.get(i).toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase(), i) != -1)
            {
                printLn(name.get(i));
            }
            else
            {
                printLn("nope");
            }
        }


        promptCommand();
    }
```

I'm trying to allow the user to search for a name they have entered through characters. I've mostly ironed out the bugs, but I'd also like them to be able to do it without worrying about case. I searched this matter, and follwed the instructions offered, and it's still case sensitive.

Anyone mind helping me out?

More info: name is what I'm calling the arraylist. Thanks everbody for your input, ill try out eavh solution when I get the chance.

Comment: You should do [equalsIgnoreCase()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29).. And iterate your ArrayList using [enhanced for-loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2).. Check out those link...

Comment: Are you matching on the entire string, or just that the name appears in part of the string? Also, text encoding (Locale) is a factor here.  What language / character set?

Answer (score 1):

[java.lang.String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29) supplies a method called `equalsIgnoreCase`:

```
for(String str : name) {
    if(str.equalsIgnoreCase(searchTerm)) {
        ....
    } else {
        ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Collections.binarySearch(name, searchTerm, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)`

(Unless you looking for `name` to be a sub-string of `searchTerm`?)

Comment: This method requires that the list is sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`equalsIgnoreCase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29) instead of `equals()`

Answer (score 1):

Use `String#contains` with lowercase.

```
for(String nm:name){
    if(nm.toLowerCase().contains(searchTerm.toLowerCase()))
        printLn(name.get(i));
    else
        printLn("nope");
}
```